# (windows) DevC++ GCC compiler hangs up or prints infinite characters

Tags: c, gcc, dev-c++

I am trying to write some C code, and while running the following, my compiler terminates abruptly, after printing 'A'. Why?

```
//report expected thing
void Expected(char *s){
int i=0;
int n = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
while (i< n)
    printf ("%c", s[i]);        
printf(" expected.\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv){
printf("%c",65);  //after this compiler hangs and asks for exit abnormally
char *Arr ={'a'};
Expected(Arr);
return 0;
}
```

Also, if I put

```
char *Arr ={"a"}; //note the double quotes
```

then it starts printing out infinite number of 'a's. Why should this happen?

Comment: Your compiler is broken. Get a new compiler that works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
```

is not how to get the length of the array of which the pointer passed as the argument points at the first element.

Pass the size of the array if you want to let your function know that.

```
char *Arr ={'a'};
```

Is not good because `'a'` is a integer and you converted it to a pointer, then the result has too little chance to be a valid pointer.

```
char *Arr ={"a"};
```

is OK because it is a valid pointer, but it will be infinite loop because `i` is not updated in the `while` loop.

The type of `main()` function is implementation-defined. You should use standard type unless you have some reason to use special `main()`.

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//report expected thing
void Expected(const char *s, size_t n){ /* add const because the contents of array won't be modified */
    size_t i=0; /* use size_t to match type of n */
    while (i < n)
        printf ("%c", s[i++]); /* update i */
    printf(" expected.\n");
}

int main(void){ /* use standard main(). int main(int argc, char **argv) is the another standard type */
    printf("%c",65);  //after this compiler hangs and asks for exit abnormally
    char Arr[] ={'a'}; /* declare an array instead of a pointer */
    Expected(Arr, sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, if it is *really* not your produced executable but *your compiler* that is crashing, throw the broken compiler away and get a new one.

Comment: I forgot the increment, my bad. Everything is fine after that. One question however, does C implicitly treat characters as integers? I saw this when i do "printf(%c, 65)", it spits out a character.

Comment: Yes, it does. `char` is one of *standard integer types*, according to [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.2.5 Types.